# Can Forefront clients report back when not connected to domain

Tags: microsoft-forefront

We're looking to deploy Microsoft Forefront to a number of clients on our network. A number of laptops are outside our domain but do have internet access.

I've read that Forefront can fall back to Windows Update to download the latest definitions if it can't contact the server. How would the reporting work? Would the clients that aren't connected to the domain be able to report the updates to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reporting is handled through a Microsoft Operations Manager agent (or if you're on a newer ForeFront than we've got, a SCCM agent) rather than from ForeFront directly. That communication happens over [specific port combinations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/904866) and aren't relying on domain credentials. So long as that communications channel is still able to be used, reporting will still populate to the reporting server.